# How to avoid online orders sending stock into negative

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to figure out how to avoid stock going into negative in the ERP. Problem as follows;

1. Customer online orders certain items we do not keep in stock. Stock goes into -1,-2 etc.
2. I then order the items to fulfil the order via the purchase ordering, Upon delivery stock goes back to "0"
3. This action does not release the order from Stockless to Full stock orders. I then have to manually change the mass stock editor to reflect the needed changes.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable "Decrease Stock When Order is Placed".

1. Go to `System ->> Configuration`
2. Click on `Inventory` in the left side menu pane
3. Open the `Stock Options` section
4. Change the `Decrease Stock When Order is Placed` to `No`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, For those specific items that are ordered one off, this process is fine. However, only half of my stock lines are like this and the other half are in the 100's. I still need to monitor these levels as orders are placed. Any thoughts?